Technical Question on Ignition Back Pressure
I am looking for understanding the backpressure or pressure stabilization of the injector inlet of the engines, during ignition (T-0). Are there books or papers that you suggest to check for calculations regarding the backpressure?
Of course there is the dynamic pressure recovery equations that could be modelled, but is that the only way?
For a numerical project that I am working on.
